# Query across schemas in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL, I have a table which, due to sharding, exists across many schemas.  In sub-optimal cases, I need to execute a query on all of these schemas (due to an exception which violates the sharding interface.. but that's another story).  What is an efficient way to do this?  Assuming the tables have an index across the data that is interesting to this particular query (that is going across all schemas.)

Comment: You're going to have to tell us more than just this. What do the tables look like? How are they indexed?

Comment: @Colin'tHart - Index on the field of interest (last name).  Tables have a first and last name, a count, and a user id (that is used for sharding).

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think an important point is being missed here.  I am querying across thousands of schemas.  So it's not the same as querying a single schema/table, and the usual optimizations do not apply.

Comment: The number of _schemas_ is irrelevant for the performance of a single query. A query accessing table from many schemas is not slower than the same query accessing tables from a single schema. As it stands your question is impossible to answer.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: If that's the case, I think you just answered my question :)  As I understand it now, I must do a different query for each schema.  For example, FROM schema.table SELECT .... so one query per schema -- but you imply that I can query all schemas at once somehow.  If that's the case I will be very grateful if you let me know how!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A construct like the following should work for you:

```
select *
from (
  select *
  from schemaA.tableA
  union all
  select *
  from schemaB.tableB
  union all
  ...
)
where columnA = "value";
```

You'll have to check the execution plans to see if the optimizer is smart enough to push the where clause into the subquery for each table.

---

The other thing to remember is that you can generate your queries by querying the metadata for a list of schema and table names.